# creating simple dependent jquery select box not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, drop-down-menu

Trying to make a dependent select box.
I have two models, Areas and buildings, one area have many buildings, so in that case the parent select box will be (Areas) and the child is (Buildings).

On my php page i query all the areas row in parent select box , and query for all buildings in child select box.

First: The Parent select box (Areas):-

```
<select id="buildgs"  onchange="showBuildings()">
    @foreach ($areas as $a)
      <option value="{{$a->name}}">{{$a->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

The above code result :-

```
<select id="buildgs" " onchange="showBuildings()">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
```

Second: The child select (Buildings):-

```
<select id="building" >
   <option value=""></option>
   @foreach ($areas as $a)
      @foreach($a->buildings as $b)
          <option style="display: none" id="{{$a->name}}" value="{{$b->id}}">
          @if($b->symbol)
               {{$b->symbol}} ({{$b->name}})
          @else
               {{$b->name}}
          @endif
          </option>
       @endforeach
    @endforeach
 </select>
```

The above code result :-

```
<select id="building">
     <option style="display: none" id="A" value="58">
                            STFA Land Area Workshop
     </option>
     <option style="display: none" id="A" value="121">
                            Temporary offices
     </option>
     <option style="display: none" id="B" value="60">
                            TC (Training Center)
     </option>
     <option style="display: none" id="B" value="110">
                            STFA Onshore Cabins
     </option>
     <option style="display: none" id="B" value="111">
                            STFA Onshore WS
     </option>
 </select>
```

Jquery and Javascript code:-

```
    <script>
      function showBuildings(){
         //getting the value from Parent (Areas)
            var x = $("#buildgs").val();
         //This one just for testing and it's working
            document.getElementById('testt').innerHTML='this changed to '+ x;

//This supposed to change all child <option>.style with x id but it not doing any thing !!!!!
            document.getElementById(x).style.display='display';
                        }
     </script>
```

Comment: To start with: `ID`'s should be unique, if you need to target a group of elements that share same identifier then I would recommend you replace using `id` for `class`. If you read the selector you will see it targets **1** element, not multiple `getElementById()` whereas `getElementsByClassName()` will target multiple elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, The `id` property must be unique, replace them with `class`.

Change this line:

`<option style="display: none" id="{{$a->name}}" value="{{$b->id}}">`

To:

`<option style="display: none" class="{{$a->name}}" value="{{$b->id}}">`

And change this line:

```
document.getElementById(x).style.display='display';
```

To:

```
var results = document.getElementsByClassName(x);
for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
   results[i].style.display='display';
}
```

**UPDATE**

I see that you use jQuery to retrieve the value of the select box, here is a clean method with less code to achieve what you want:

```
<select id="buildgs"  onchange="showBuildings(this.value)">
```

Your new function:

```
  <script>
      function showBuildings(val){
            $('#building option').not('.'+val).hide(); // Don't forget this!
            $('#building option.' + val).show();
      }
  </script>
```

Comment: Won't you need to select the element index? `getElementsByClassName()[]` since this returns a collection of elements.

Comment: Yeah I noticed, I thought I would point it out so you could edit the answer before others start to downvote you for it.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined
    at showBuildings (create:808)
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (create:816)
showBuildings @ create:808
onchange @ create:816

Comment: I have changed the code , same as your latest answer update, now no error is showing in console but when i select in parent select box nothing changed in child, if you mean by ID the class name , the class name is same as parent name which is only letters (A,B,C)

Comment: The result of : alert(results[1]); is ==> [object HTMLOptionElement] , i don't know if it mean something , i am new in JS

Comment: @user2873860 I won't post this as a solution because I have pretty much removed all of your javascript and replaced it with `jQuery` but since you have `jQuery` loaded and seem to be using bits of it `var x = $("#buildgs").val();` why not take advantage and use it to slim down the source code and make things easier to work with? [**JsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/992b9mLL/)

Comment: @NewToJS already did that 5min ago within my updated answer :)

Comment: @Boratzan I didn't see the update until after posting that comment, I were on a different tab writing that out for the OP but you have taken a better approach and used `.show()` / `.hide()` which will then allow the OP to remove the inline styles.

Comment: This worked $('option.' + val).show(); , but there is a problem with it, is that when i selected in parent the area (A) all it related buildings showed in child, then when i select in parent (B) the child will show buildings for both Areas (A+B) , if i select (C) it will show in child (A+B+C), I need some code to be inserted top of the function to hide all child building then show $('option.' + val).show();

Comment: It's also included in my answer, you didn't use all parts of my code. This line will do that: `$('#building option').not('.'+val).hide();`